# Unity 2017 UnityContainer will not resolve

Tags: unity-game-engine, unity-container

I am having a ton of trouble trying to use UnityContainer. Unity will not compile my scripts as it keeps giving me this message :

```
 The type or namespace name `Unity' could not be found. Are you missing an assembly reference?
```

And

```
The type or namespace name `UnityContainer' could not be found. Are you missing an assembly reference?
```

I have been digging around on the web for ages, and have found some people with similar, but not exactly the same problem.  So far I have tried :

1. Uninstalling / Reinstalling Unity (2017.3.0f3)
2. Uninstalling / Reinstalling Visual Studio ( 2017 )
3. Changed unity player settings to use Experimental .NET 4.6 equivilant

I have used NuGet to install the Unity Container project, and everything resolves and builds fine in Visual Studio, but Unity keeps giving the missing Namespace error.

I am completely stuck, and at a bit of a loss because I need to use the features UnityContainer provides in order to progress with my game.  I have considered using an older version of Unity, but I really want to use the new tilemaps feature.  I would be incredibly grateful for any assistance.

Comment: Not sure if this is the problem or not, but have been poking around in VS, and when I look in my references folder, there is no "Unity" assembly.  I assume that VS is pulling the reference from installed packages, but maybe this is why Unity cannot see it.  Annoyingly though there is no option to add a reference like I would in a non Unity project

Comment: Namespace is UnityEngine, not just Unity. Where are you using it?

Comment: In order to use dependency injection, you have to add a nuget package which adds a Unity namespace, containing the appropriate back end for doing DI.  It seems it is an issue using packages from nuget.  I have been following this article : http://www.what-could-possibly-go-wrong.com/unity-and-nuget/  but I still cannot get things working properly.  It just seems mad as there are tons of references to people using this, but not many to people having problems with it